# How to click a expand button if ID is randomly generated

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, c#

I have a problem how to click a desired expand button if ID is randomly generated.
This means that the ID has another value after refresh page.
Of course, the ID has another value for each row.
I don't know how to click on expand button for 1st Field, 1st Operator, 2nd Field....etc.
Here is a code for a first row, 1st Field button:

[image]

Here is a code for a first row, 1st Operator button:

[image]

Here is a code for a second row, 1st Field button:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture a `List` of elements. Then the first row will be the first element of the list and so on. Your html structure makes it quite simple, so for the *field* elements it would be:

```
IList<IWebElement> fields = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("table[id='advFilter'] td[class='field'] div[class='apidrop apidicon']"));
fields[0].Click();
```

The selector used here is looking into the table with `id=advFilter`, then looks for a `td` element with `class=field`, then for the button - which is located inside a `div` with a `class=apidrop apidicon`.

For other elements you need to change the `td` classname.

Comment: Honestly, I still have no idea how to do it.
Can you explain more details, please?
In C#, please.

Comment: I have changed the code to c#. This code should expand the "Field" list from your screenshots.

Comment: This solution works as expected. Thank you very much.